# iOS analyse crash report file

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports, dsym

I have been googling a lot about how to analyze a crash file and find out what is the problem in my app.
Many posts are suggesting different solutions to many scenarios.
My scenario is as follows : 
I deliver the source code to another developer. The other developer generates a release with Bamboo then he sends the link for uploading the .ipa file.
The QA tests the applications and generates crash reports with Xcode organizer and sends them to me.
However, when i look at the crash files i see no clear indication about the cause of the crash (some hexadecimal stuff).
Some posts show how to analyze crash reports using the crash log and the DSYM file. But since i do not have a DSYM, i use "atos" command in terminal and analyze the addresses. But all i have is some weird output.
For example:

**MacBook-Pro-de-macbook:folder atos -arch armv7 -o MyApp.app/MyApp 0x5c9fff** i get **0x005c9fff (in MyApp)**

Could someone please tell if there is a straight way for analyzing a crash report ? should i ask the other developer to provide the .DSYM file ? Is there a way to interpret the hexadecimal addresses and get the exact lines where the crash occurred ?

Comment: Yes, you need the dSYM file to symbolicate the crash report.

Comment: So you mean if i get the dSYM file, i will be able to exactly locate the crash. Correct ?

Comment: As long as the dSYM is from the exact same build that generated the crash report, then yes.